# Able to scan file using VirusTotal but unable to get the report on the scan

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to use the VirusTotal scanning platform when running the asp.net application with the C# backend

based on the instruction here is the class that I created

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;

namespace MyTransaction
{
    public class VirusTotal
    {
        public string APIKey;
        //string scan = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/scan_file.json";
        string scan = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan";
        //string results = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/get_file_report.json";
        string results = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report";

        public VirusTotal(string apiKey)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            APIKey = apiKey;
        }

        public string Scan(string file)
        {
            var v = new NameValueCollection();
            v.Add("key", APIKey);
            var c = new WebClient() { QueryString = v };
            c.Headers.Add("Content-type", "binary/octet-stream");
            byte[] b = c.UploadFile(scan, "POST", file);
            string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(b);
            var r = ParseJSON(json);
            if (r.ContainsKey("scan_id"))
            {
                return r["scan_id"];
            }
            throw new Exception(r["result"]);
        }

        public string GetResults(string id)
        {
            //Clipboard.SetText(id);
            var data = string.Format("resource={0}&key={1}", id, APIKey);
            var c = new WebClient();
            string s = c.UploadString(results, "POST", data);
            var r = ParseJSON(s);
            foreach (string str in r.Values)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(str);
            }
            if (r["result"] != "1")
            {
                throw new Exception(r["result"]);
            }
            return s;
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> ParseJSON(string json)
        {
            var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            json = json.Replace("\"", null).Replace("[", null).Replace("]", null);
            var r = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2).Split(',');
            foreach (string s in r)
            {
                d.Add(s.Contains(":") ? s.Split(':')[0] : s, s.Contains(":") ? s.Split(':')[1] : s);
            }
            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the scan method, I get the this JSON response

```
{"md5":"00f8ce8792add97bf6d65d0977e85779",
"permalink":"f-9a8e7cf81457757398b6a8f4351af97d9c81acdc9dd89ccf48086fffe1532dc-705607202",
"resource":"89a8e7cf81457757398b6a8f4351af97d9c81acdc9dd89ccf48086fffe1532dc",
"response_code":1,
"scan_id":"89a8e7cf81457757398b6a8f4351af97d9c81acdc9dd89ccf48086fffe1532dc-705607202",
"sha1":"ef3517244d69873c95694d66f27f90cac65e2fd5",
"sha256":"89a8e7cf81457757398b6a8f4351af97d9c81acdc9dd89ccf48086fffe1532dc",
"verbose_msg":"Scan request successfully queued, come back later for the report"}
```

But I am simply unable to use this information to get the report on the file

I tried

```
curl --request GET --url "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/report?apikey=myapikey&scan_id=89a8e7cf81457757398b6a8f4351af97d9c81acdc9dd89ccf48086fffe1532dc-705607202&resource=89a8e7cf81457757398b6a8f4351af97d9c81acdc9dd89ccf48086fffe1532dc"
```

That returned

> {"resource":"89a8e7cf81457757398b6a8f4351af97d9c81acdc9dd89ccf48086fffe1532dc","response_code":0,"verbose_msg":"Resource
> does not exist in the dataset"}

No matter what I do I get the message that the resource doesn't exist or an empty JSON

Can some one suggest how to properly get the report on the VirusTotal scan result?

Thank you everyone in advance

Comment: The response does say to "come back later for the report". Is it possible that you're requesting the report before it's done scanning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

Instead of

> --url "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/**url**/report?

I should have used

> --url "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/**file**/report?